# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.iTunesLib, Version=1.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, dll, itunes

I'm trying to access iTunes using C#.
The steps are to write a dll in C# and execute it with TypeScript using Overwolf API.

What I did

Generate .dll

I introduced iTunesLib based on [this](https://www.tetsuyanbo.net/tetsuyanblog/11027). Sorry for the Japanese article..

I created a ClassLibrary project in Visual Studio and tested it in a Windows Forms application. This worked.

Then built ClassLibrary and generated a .dll file.

```
namespace MyNamespace{
  public class MyClass {
    public void myFunction() {
      iTunesLib.iTunesAppClass iTunesApp = new iTunesLib.iTunesAppClass();
      // do something with iTunesApp ....
    }
  }
}
```

Call C# function in Typescript

```
overwolf.extensions.current.getExtraObject("myNamespace", (result) => {
        
  if (result.success) {
    pluginInstance = result.object;
    pluginInstance.myFunction(); // Call C# function
  }
}
```

Error report

> ERROR: Error: Failed to execute PauseITunes on AudioController with 0 arguments. details:
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: target threw an exception ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.iTunesLib, Version=1.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies when deploying the application
> Where MyNamespace.MyClass.myFunction()

---

It worked in Windows Form Application, but why does it stop working when I build it into a dll? The error seems to be occurring in the iTunesLib part.

Comment: When you call your `Generate.dll`, did you copied this `iTunesLib` on the same folder? If not, try to copy this `iTunesLib` too alongside your `Generate.dll` and check if this error still occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Heinz Siahaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4715873/heinz-siahaan) said, I was able to solve the problem by placing `interop.iTunesLib.dll` in the same hierarchy.

Thank you so much.